# How to clone a folder of shared drive and push locally through git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am a newbie of GIT and I want to clone a folder on shared drive, say shared\folder, to a local directory, say local\folder. First, I initialize the repository:

```
> cd shared\folder
> git init
> git add -A
> git commit -m "message"
> git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

and then I clone the folder

```
> cd local\folder
> git clone 'shared\folder'
```

and then I use sourcetree to add the local\folder as a working repository. Everything works just fine, I can push the local change to the shared\folder.
However, most of my colleagues don't use git and they change the file directly on the shared\folder. I can't pull the changes from the shared\folder. Is there any possible way to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to periodically commit the work that you co-workers do in the shared folder.  You could also set up a cron job to do it automatically - then you should be able to pull and get the latest

Comment: Could you elaborate "set up a clone job to do it automatically"?

Comment: not clone, cron.  The linux cron is the mechanism used to execute scripts on a timed basis.  you can create a script that does something like "git add -A; git commit -m"cron commit"  You can work variables in like the date, time, etc.